# Changing tedge/2 predicate from Lu & Mead's Prolog: A Tutorial Introduction

Tags: prolog

the booklet "Prolog: A tutorial Introduction", by James Lu and Jerud Mead (available as a PDF in the Internet) features the predicate tedge/2 like this:

```
tedge(Node1,Node2) :-
   edge(Node1,SomeNode),
   edge(SomeNode,Node2).
```

I would like to change it to accept only nodes not directly connected by an edge. There's an easy way:

```
    tedge(Node1,Node2) :-
       edge(Node1,SomeNode),
       edge(SomeNode,Node2),
       \+ edge(Node1,Node2).
```

But when I imposed that `Node1`, `SomeNode`, and `Node2` should be different, like this:

```
tedge(Node1,Node2):-
   edge(Node1,SomeNode),
   edge(SomeNode,Node2),
   Node1 \= Node2, Node1 \= SomeNode, Node2 \= SomeNode.
```

It didn't work as expected. That is: for nodes a and b where with edge(a,b), the predicate tedge(a,b) would be true.

Could you please tell me why ?

Answer (score 2):

First, `\+ edge(Node1,Node)` should probably be `\+ edge(Node1,Node2)` in  `tedge/2`.

Second, you forgot exactly this goal in the second definition of `tedge/2`.

---

#### Edit 2015-04-29

Consider the following graph:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(a,c).
```

Here's your second definition of `tedge/2`:

```
tedge(Node1,Node2) :-
       edge(Node1,SomeNode),
       edge(SomeNode,Node2),
       \+ edge(Node1,Node2).
```

So, does `tedge(a,c)` hold? **No!**

Why? Two necessary goals `edge(Node1,SomeNode)` and `edge(SomeNode,Node2)` succeed (with bindings `Node1 = a` and `Node2 = c`), but `\+ edge(Node1,Node2)` fails, as `edge(a,c)` clearly *is* provable (above, we stated it as a plain fact).

Here's your third definition of `tedge/2`:

```
tedge(Node1,Node2):-
   edge(Node1,SomeNode),
   edge(SomeNode,Node2),
   Node1 \= Node2, Node1 \= SomeNode, Node2 \= SomeNode.
```

Does `tedge(a,c)` hold with this definition? **Yes!**

Why? As before the first two goals `edge(Node1,SomeNode)` and `edge(SomeNode,Node2)` succeed (with bindings `Node1 = a`, `Node2 = c`, `SomeNode = b`). So what about the pairwise disequalities? They hold **too**, as the goals `a \= c, a \= b, c \= b` succeed.

Comment: My bad: i posted the 1st version from memory, not for code. Thanks, @paulo-mora for the edition and correction. 

But concerning the answer by repeat, my point is exactly why the triple inequality in the 2nd version is not respected, if as far as i can see it supposedly imposes the need that no existing edge should be allowed ?

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand you correctly: Do you suppose that the goal `\+ edge(Node1,Node2)` is implied by the pairwise disequalities? I don't think so: rather, that depends on the graph defined by `edge/2`.

Comment: Dear friend, i do think so, and indeed your question raised some doutbts. I do believe that the form using disequalities is superior, as it will correctly allow a direct edge between Node 1 and Node2, provided there are two other edges, one from Node1 to SomeNode, and another from SomeNode to Node2.

Since my experience with Prolog is practically none, would mind explaining why my assumptions are wrong ?

Comment: Dear friend, i'm a total newcomer to Prolog and to StackOverflow. Please do what you think it is necessary to solve this interesting problem. 

Thank you !

Comment: Thanks a lot @repeat, for your patience and excellent explanation skills. 

I believe i was taken by beginner's anxiety. Your explanation is very clear. 

But please consider another graph, like 
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(a,d).

In this case, both the 2nd and the 3rd definition would find the correct answer. 

That is: the 3rd form is indeed superior, for it can find indirect paths, even when there's a direct edge.

Thanks again. I count on you to answer my further Prolog questions. 8-) 

Have a nice week.